# Selenium webdriver script failing to locate button even with ID

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm hoping this is easier than it seems and I've just gone snow blind trying to fix it!  Your help would be massively appreciated on this.

I am using the PageObject Model (I think!) to create my tests.  I have an object which replicates the browsing for and uploading of an image, which I am having to call an AutoIt script to accomplish.  This works but having uploaded the image the 'upload' button is not being located even though it has an ID attribute.

It is correctly being enabled following the file selection so unsure what I'm missing.

The code for the PageObject is:

```
public void AddImage(string FileDescription, int DocNo, int Revision, string StatusLstItem, string CreationDate)
{

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Button1")).Click();
    driver.SwitchTo().Window("FileDetails");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Description1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Description1")).SendKeys(FileDescription);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocNo1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocNo1")).SendKeys(DocNo.ToString());
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("revision1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("revision1")).SendKeys(Revision.ToString());
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileStatus1"))).SelectByText(StatusLstItem);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("creationDate1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("creationDate1")).SendKeys(CreationDate);
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Filename1"));
    element.Click();
    Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\FileUploadCr.exe");
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement upload = driver.FindElement(By.Id("action1"));
    upload.Click();
}
```

I am then calling the '`AddImage`' method from the test class using the following:

```
[Test]
public void ItemChecks()
{
    InformationObject informationObject = new InformationObject(driver);

    informationObject.ExpandAllButton();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    informationObject.AddImage("SampleDesc", 01, 01, "Approved", "01/10/2012");
    informationObject.ClickUpdateButtonOne();
}
```

For some reason it is not finding/clicking the 'action1' upload button.  I have tried switching back to the 'FileDetails' window but this also does not work.

Any ideas what is I'm missing???

FYI - the code for the Upload button is:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Upload" id="action1" disabled=""/>
```

UPDATE - the amended + working PageObject method now looks like this:

```
public void AddImage(string FileDescription, int DocNo, int Revision, string StatusLstItem, string CreationDate)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Button1")).Click();
    driver.SwitchTo().Window("FileDetails");
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Filename1"));
    element.Click();
    Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\AutoIt_Files\\FileUploadCr.exe");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Description1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Description1")).SendKeys(FileDescription);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocNo1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocNo1")).SendKeys(DocNo.ToString());
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("revision1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("revision1")).SendKeys(Revision.ToString());
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileStatus1"))).SelectByText(StatusLstItem);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("creationDate1")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("creationDate1")).SendKeys(CreationDate);
    driver.SwitchTo().Window("FileDetails");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    IWebElement upload = driver.FindElement(By.Id("action1"));
    upload.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss(); //Ignore this, just an alert that displays following upload and not part of the solution
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using

```
driver.FindElement(By.id("action1")).submit();
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi_Mishra, I have tried that but get the following: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException : Element was not in a form, so could not submit.

Comment: This tells that Upload button is not loaded probably.So try to sleep(Thread.sleep()) or wait before clicking upload and if you dont have any problem then shift the line to execute autoit at the top of method.

Comment: YES! Seems so obvious now you mentioned it. I moved the Process call further up, added a thread.sleep and changed it back to upload.Click() (didn't like .submit) and now working perfectly.

Comment: @Arran, sorry about that, still learning the etiquette! Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that we are facing here is that the Selenium Web Driver can't locate the "Upload Button".

The method that you had used is FindBy. Id.

I also face the same issue.

Try using the different identifiers. 
For me CSSSelector Works.

Eg: driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("CssSelectorName")).Click();

Note : You can use firepath / firebug for getting Xpath, CSS Selector for more convenience.

Comment: Yup, Formatte. Thanks for the suggestion